# Node.js - How to initialise/define req.body?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get the error - "Cannot read property 'score' of undefined" at "var score - req.body.score". In order to do this I'm guessing I need to define and/or initialise 'req.body' (I'm pretty new to Node.js), any idea how I do this?

Here's my Node.JS code as it stands:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

console.log('Game server running...'); 

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
console.log('Player submitted high-score:');

var score = req.body.score;
  console.log(score);   

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
res.end('_testcb(\'"Your high-score has been submitted."\')'); 
}).listen(80);
```

Below is the HTML with the input text field and a submit button:

```
Your score: <input id="score" name="score" type="text"></input>
<button id="SubmitBtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

And also below is the JavaScript within the HTML (Just in case it helps answer my question):

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#SubmitBtn').click(function (event) {
$.ajax({ 
url: 'http://localhost',
data: { score : $("input[name='score']").val() },
dataType: "jsonp", 
jsonpCallback: "_testcb", 
cache: false, 
timeout: 5000, 
success: function(data) { 
    $("#test").append(data); 
}, 
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert('Error connecting to the Node.js server... ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown); 
} 
}); 
});
});
```

Basically, I want to get the input from a input text field called 'score' from a HTML doc, but getting the error "Cannot read property 'score' of undefined" at 'var score - req.body.score'. Guessing I need to initialise/define 'req.body somewhere but I don't know how? Can anyone help me out?

Also, I've found this online about initialising/defining 'res.body', could be useful??

```
req.on('response', function (res) {
    res.body = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        res.body += chunk;
    });

res.on('end', function () {
     console.log(res.body);
});
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know whether some “middleware” provides `req.body`, but to continue down that path:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var qs = require('querystring');

console.log('Game server running...'); 

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
    console.log('Player submitted high-score:');

    var bodyParts = [];

    req.on("data", function(part) {
        bodyParts.push(part);
    });

    req.on("end", function() {
        var body = Buffer.concat(bodyParts).toString("utf8");
        var data = qs.parse(data);

        var score = data.score;
        console.log(score);

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
        res.end('_testcb(\'"Your high-score has been submitted."\')'); 
    });
}).listen(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `request.body` property is populated by the bodyParser middleware, so you have to include that in the node.js app as well

```
app.use(express.bodyParser())
```

so

```
var http    = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

console.log('Game server running...'); 

app.use(express.bodyParser())

console.log('Player submitted high-score:');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var score = req.body.score;
    console.log(score);   
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
    res.end('_testcb(\'"Your high-score has been submitted."\')'); 
});

app.listen(80);
```

`req` is the request, containing data from the current request, and `res` is the response you send back from the server, so trying to get the data from the input from the respone you send back is not going to work.